# Grouping similar texts in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, text-mining

I got employee designation data having so much unique values.
I want to club together many forms of one designation together like ('Senior Manager', 'Sr. Manager', 'Sen manager', 'Snr Manager' etc). Also this data is having typo mistakes as well.

What will be the best technique for clubbing many designations into one using R.

Is clustering best way to solve this issue or can some other technique help better to solve my problem.

I tried 'euclidean distance' and k-means but none gave satisfactory results.

```
library(tm)
library(data.table)
library(SparseM)
library(cluster)
    data <- readLines('RDATA.txt')
    head(data)
```

[image]

```
        data <- data[1:50]
        source <- VectorSource(data)
        corpus <- Corpus(source)
        corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
        corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
        corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
        corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
        corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
    dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,
                             control = list(
                               wordLengths=c(4, 15),

                             ))
    m  <- as.matrix(dtm)
    distMatrix <- dist(m, method="euclidean")
    groups <- hclust(distMatrix,method="ward.D" )
    groups2 <-cutree(groups, k=10)
    clus_data <-cbind(data,groups2)
    clus_data
```

Comment: You should add your own stopwords, if everybody's a manager and it's not important for example you should remove it. You can also list all distinct words, pass them through a spell check, and manually assign a translation to those that don't pass the spell check.

Comment: This distance matrix is only looking at words btw, not spelling, so maybe what you want is something like `stringdist::stringdist`

Comment: Can you include more data ? maybe 50 rows, and please copy paste them, never use image captures of tables on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work this way.

Just consider "dog", "fog". These words are similar, but you don't want them to be clustered. It's not just a typo.

Because of this, you cannot use an unsupervised method like clustering. You need something **trained** on *language*, typical spelling mistakes, and maybe phonetics.